# LWC how to dynamically toggle required attribute for lightning-textarea

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a need to toggle / add / remove the required attribute for a lightning-textarea. I can use the add and remove attribute but it does not seem to work and the UI is not updated. I assume it is setting it in the HTML DOM but not the shadow DOM.

```
this.template
          .querySelector(querySelector)
          .setAttribute("required", "true");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties can be set directly:

```
this.template.querySelector(querySelector).required = true; // or false
```

No need to call `setAttribute` to make attributes stick on a custom component from the outside.